# Why gesture start working outside of frame in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have a Rec that I can move it in gesture action, but the problem is that gesture start capturing gesture in outside of its frame, which I expect just working inside the frame. here is the code and gif about issue:

gif:

[image]

code:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var recLocation: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    @GestureState private var recTranslation: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            Rectangle().fill(Color.red).frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                .position(x: recLocation + recTranslation + 25, y: geometry.size.height/2)
                .gesture( DragGesture()
                            .updating($recTranslation) { value, state, translation in
                                state = value.translation.width
                            }
                            .onEnded { value in
                                recLocation = recLocation + value.translation.width
                            } )
            
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I think .position() covers all the available container space. Because .gesture() is attached (comes after) .position(), that's what ends up receiving the event. Perhaps you could try moving .gesture() before .position() and see what happens?

Answer (score 2):

From what I know every time I use `GeometryReader` the sizes of my container gets messed up, I tried to find a solution since the first minute you have posted this question because it's very interesting and here it is how to overcome this problem:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
    
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.red)
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        .position(x: recLocation + recTranslation + 25, y: geometry.size.height/2)
        .overlay(
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 23.5, height: 23.5)
                .position(x: recLocation + recTranslation + 25, y: geometry.size.height/2)
                .opacity(0.001)
                .gesture( DragGesture()
                            .updating($recTranslation) { value, state, translation in
                                state = value.translation.width
                            }
                            .onEnded { value in
                                recLocation = recLocation + value.translation.width
                            } )
        )
    
}.frame(width: 50, height: 50)
}
```

**Explanation:**

Basically what I saw is that the `DragGesture` is detected outside the boundary of your Rectangle, by that I have created an `Overlay` with the same shape and with less size, and make the `DragGesture` to the `Overlay`.

Note: Don't forget to put the `Overlay` shape `Opacity` to 0.001, by that it will be invisible but still interactive.

Voila! everything seems perfect.

[image: Result]

Comment: @ Cod3rMax: thanks for your Answer, but i can not accepted, you are not solving the issue, you are dealing with issue!

Comment: @willy well thank you very much :) if you find a solution or something like that let me know I would be happy to know that, if no one answer as you expect i'll start a bounty maybe there will be much easier solutions.

Comment: @ Cod3rMax: definitely, for your information I could deal better with issue with reading location of X of tap or doing same thing you did in background of Rec, I am not here to deal with issue but finding out why it happens. the problem is that we are working with DragGesture() closers("I mean Apple make us to work with it"), I do not know what is the Mother Function of DragGesture(), that gives us  value, state and translation.

Comment: @willy i have submited a support request to apple engineers to explain exactly why, second thing you should post in your question what you have tried to overcome the problem and ask exactly (WHY) in your question not in your title. When i get a response from them i'll update my answer

Comment: @ Cod3rMax: thanks, I know How I can overcome to issue so easily and deal with it in one short line code, but as I said I do want solve the issue from basic not using some other code for solving the issue which should NOT be exist at all. For what I think, is this: Apple has another frame more than a frame that we can access and that frame makes problem. Like this, you make an API and you only has access to source code and to this unknown frame.